# Extraneous BufUnload event triggered in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I run vim with no file on the command-line, so that it shows the scratch buffer.  When I then run

```
:e foo
```

to edit file 'foo', there is a BufUnload event triggered for file 'foo'.  Here is a test vim command that I use to demonstrate the issue:

```
autocmd BufUnload * echom "Unloaded " . expand("<afile>")
```

Does anyone know what is causing this, and if there is a way to detect this situation and ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the latest Vim 7.4a.39. I guess this has to do with the fact that Vim reuses the initial scratch buffer number (1) for the first `:edit`ed file. Please report this problem to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: Ok; just reported it.  Any idea for how to detect this situation and ignore the BufUnload event?

Comment: Thanks! You could also hook into `BufNew,BufRead` and set a flag there. Any `BufUnload` where there's no flag set can then be discarded. What (plugin / functionality) is broken by the current bug?

Comment: Ok, that workaround seemed to work.  I think I've now found 2 other bugs with BufUnload, though.

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin that sends the contents of the buffers to a local server that runs machine learning on their contents.  I'd like to only keep in the server process's memory those buffers that are in the vim process's memory, to avoid keeping large numbers of buffers in memory.  It seemed that BufUnload would be a good way to do this.